# Using write concern with insert_one

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm upgrading to pymongo 3.6+ from earlier versions.  The collection `save()` method is now deprecated, and `insert_one` is the recommended replacement.  I'm used to using a write concern `w=1` on the `save()` method, and it's not clear to me from documentation how to properly enforce a write concern when using `insert_one()`.  How should I go about that in the late 3.x and early 4.x versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I can tell, write concern is now set globally, and individual `insert_one` operations can not change that write concern.  The default write concern is `w=1`, meaning that acknowledgement is given.  PyMongo provides an [interface to modify the global write concern](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/write_concern.html).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the with_options method. Example:

```
from pymongo.write_concern import WriteConcern
db.users.with_options(write_concern=WriteConcern(w="majority")).insert_one({"name": name, "email": email})
```

Comment: you need to import WriteConcern, so this answer is not complete. please edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can doing something like this in your code...

```
from pymongo.write_concern import WriteConcern
db.users.with_options(
    write_concern=WriteConcern(w="majority")
).insert_one(
      {"name": name, "email": email}
  )
```